# Logging in Prism

Tags: logging, prism

How do I use [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2058) Logger in Prism?
I cannot find any example projects and I don't really know how I can use this in my prism application.

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: @AlexR thank you for mentioning - now it should be working